# Table in email not centered in MS Outlook

Tags: html, css, html-table, outlook

I use the following mark-up in an HTML email to center a table. It works fine in most email clients but for some reason, in Outlook, the table appears **left aligned**, even though I have used margin auto on the left and right. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
 <table class="email-survey-type type_question" style=" width: 80%; text-align: center;  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;;" bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

```html
    <div style="font-family: 'Helvetica Nueue', Arial, sans-serif; padding: 20px; background: #fff;">

    <div style="font-family:'Helvetica Nueue', Arial, sans-serif; background: #fff; max-width: 550px; margin: 0 auto;">
        
        
    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (min-width: 430px) { .maxW { width:400px !important; } }
      </style>
        
            
            <div class="maxW" style="max-width:400px;margin: 0 auto;">

                   
                   </div><table width="100%" bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tbody><tr style="text-align: center;">

                   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="400" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><![endif]-->
                   </tr></tbody></table>
                   
                   <table class="email-survey-type type_question" style=" width: 95%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; " bgcolor="#fe5777" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                       <tbody><tr>
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="0" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #c0392b; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #e74c3c; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="4" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #f65c4c; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="6" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #e76430; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="8" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #2ecc71; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="10" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #1abc9c; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                       </tr>
                   </tbody></table>
                   <table class="email-survey-type type_question" style=" width: 80%; text-align: center;  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;;" bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                       <tbody><tr>
                          
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #c0392b; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="3" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #e74c3c; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;" >
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="5" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #e76430; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;" >
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="7" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #2ecc71; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;" >
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                               
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img alt="9" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/340px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="60" style="max-width: 60px; width:60px; color: #1abc9c; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                               
                           
                               
                           
                       </tr>
                   </tbody></table>

                   </div>
                   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                
            

            
            


            
              <table width="100%" bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody><tr style=" ">
                    <td style="padding: 20px;"><p style="text-align: center; margin: 0 0 5px; line-height: 1;font-family:'Helvetica Nueue', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:18px;" class="bottom_text_en-target show-parent-2">Lorem ipsum dolor</p></td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody></table>
        

        

        <!-- End links -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Outlook doesn't support `margin`. Use `<table align="center">` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You email most likely will have more bugs and issues, you are suing `<div>` which is not supported or have some issues. Outlook 2007-2016 doesn't fully support margin and it's buggy you can [check it here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/margin/).

use `align="center"`

Code:

```html
<table align="center" class="email-survey-type type_question" style=" width: 80%; text-align: center;" bgcolor="red" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Your code
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```